# MySQL INSERT INTO updates even if it shouldn't

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-into

My problem is that with a specific table in my database even if I use a simple `INSERT INTO` query the data gets updated instead of giving me a "Duplicate" error if the primary key already exists.

Structure of the table:

```
user_id (PRIMARY_KEY) | email (VARCHAR) | token (VARCHAR) | created (DATETIME)
```

If I excecute this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
            email_confirmation (
                user_id,
                email,
                token,
                created
            ) VALUES (
                :user_id,
                :email,
                :token,
                NOW()
            )";
$query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

$values = [
    ':user_id' => $customer['id'],
    ':email' => $customer['email'],
    ':token' => $token
];

$query->execute($values);
```

It will update my row instead of giving me an error if primary key already exists. Can anyone explain me why is this happening?

Comment: your `user_id` is a `PRIMARY_KEY` not a `UNIQUE_KEY` so that column will increment instead.

Comment: @Alex, it's wrong. PK always unique, and never increment when provided

Comment: @Alex why should it increment if I don't use `auto_increment`?

Comment: may be some triggers here, or your `$this->connection` adds `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`  clause...

Comment: @vp_arth anyways he should use an `UNIQUE_KEY`

Comment: @Alex, for what?? it's stupid - create unique index on field, where already primary key index created

Comment: @vp_arth I don't add any clause. I have another function which will create a customer with a similar structure and in that case if I try to add the same customer it will give me a "Duplicate" error. It's driving me crazy...

Comment: are you sure, that old user exists before?

Comment: @vp_arth There it is...for debugging purpouse I was previously deleting all the rows in the table and it was creating them again. I completely forgot about this as I had "commented" this step in my code previously. I feel really stupid right now...thank you!!

Comment: There is not magic again :)

Comment: Can you post the results of a `SHOW CREATE TABLE email_confirmation`. Also, I need to reiterate that everything @Alex has said thusfar is wrong.